# How can I make my browser lie about my operating system?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, browser, javascript

I'm using Chromium (Version 30.0.1599.114 Ubuntu 12.10) under Linux. I'm trying to access [a website](http://learn.livemocha.com/) that claims that it doesn't work under Linux. Of course, this is most likely crazy since the web is platform-independent (unless they're using some kind of evil plug-in).

I've used a user agent switcher to supply a Windows user agent, but to no avail. Upon viewing the source, it appears that the site is using Javascript to determine the operating system. I'm looking for a way to get my browser to report in Javascript that it is Windows or MacOS.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Check in dev tools -> settings -> overrides (works on my Chrome .. afaik chrome / chromium are almost the same)

Comment: @Abhishek I checked it out, Chromium has the same set up.

Comment: as you are looking at the source, can you share what, exactly, the code is checking to infer your OS? might be easier to get a spoof working

Comment: @Abhishek: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that only allows the user agent string to be spoofed, which doesn't help in this case.

Comment: @Hashbrown: Reading through the source, it appears to be using `navigator.userAgent` and grepping for `linux`. However, since I'm spoofing the user agent string, my `navigator.userAgent` is now `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0` yet the site still knows somehow that I'm on Linux.

Comment: Note: The Javascript is minified and trying to step through it in the debugger is painfully slow, never mind that minified code is really difficult to understand. Also, I've edited the question to link to the site at issue.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808968/change-navigator-platform-on-chrome-firefox-or-ie-to-test-os-detection-code for how to create a simple Chrome extension to do this. Some scripts rely on navigator.platform to determine the OS and you can change it using that extension (though it changes it to MacIntel, but you could simply put the equivalent Linux string in there instead).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the javascript is using [`navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.userAgent) to infer your OS yet you have tried [changing the useragent string](http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/16/change-user-agent-chrome-safari-firefox/).

It may be [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99418) <sub>(not that one, since you're running v30)</sub>, you should go [here to test](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) if it is or not. If so you may have to try an [alternative](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) to the inbuilt dev tools that hopefully tries something fancy to get the same effect.

Comment: It *does* appear to be using `navigator.userAgent`. However, it's clearly using something else in addition. I've verified multiple ways that my user agent string is in fact being changed, yet the problem persists. So, much as I'd like it to be so, changing the user agent isn't the answer--or at least isn't the complete answer.

Comment: Flash or Java may be revealing somehow, though I don't know exactly how they would be doing it.  It's also possible to infer your OS from your installed fonts.